# How to draw a poset Hasse Diagram using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I need to draw an [Hasse Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) using LaTeX. TikZ is the solution I would like to use. I tried with a simple structure involving trees but obviously when I need to join two nodes, it is not possible.

I searched a little but found no immediate solutions for Hasse Diagrams in TikZ. Which one is the fastest structure I can use? I would like also to have the tree syntax flexibility without manually specifying where nodes should be places. I just want to specify nodes and connections.

Comment: have a look at [these node positioning examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/node-positioning/). A Hasse Diagram basically looks like a bunch of nodes, an TikZ is very good at drawing bunches of nodes. These examples should help you to get going.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Here is a *brief* tutorial to get you *started:*  As in any other piece of software, break it down into its components.

1. First step is to draw the nodes and give them name.  Lets start with the top node located at the origin and name it `(top)`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node (top) at (0,0) {$\{x,y\}$};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

   So now you have:

   [image]

   which is not too exciting.

   **Note:** I included the full code here, but subsequent steps I show only the additions to the above to make it easier to follow.
2. Next, add the left and right nodes.  These should be located relative to the `(top)` node so that in case we decide to move the position of the top node, these two will move along with it:

   ```
   \node [below left  of=top] (left)  {$x$};
   \node [below right of=top] (right) {$y$};
   ```

   So, now things a looking a bit more useful:

   [image]

   If these are not far enough apart, you could move them, again relatively, by using something like `xshift=<length>`, or `xshift=<length>`.
3. Next step is to draw the lines connecting these nodes via their node names (color used here to see the correspondence between the code and the output):

   ```
   \draw [red,  thick] (top) -- (left);
   \draw [blue, thick] (top) -- (right);
   ```

   to get:

   [image]

   If the lines are not long enough you can shorten then via a negative amount. For the top we use `shorten <=-2pt`, and for the bottom  `shorten >=-2pt` to get:

   [image]

   Using the `to` syntax as opposed to the `--` allows you to get fancier and control the angle at the out point via `out=<angle>`, and the angle of the line coming in via `in=<angle>`:

   ```
   \draw [red,  thick, shorten <=-2pt, shorten >=-2pt, out=-120, in=90] (top) to (left);
   \draw [blue, thick, shorten <=-2pt, shorten >=-2pt, out=-60,  in=90] (top) to (right);
   ```

   which if it had been used below would have produced:

   [image]

   As pointed out by Paul Gaborit, the `out` and `in` options are really only for the `to` directive so some might prefer a syntax that more explicitly places those options for the `to` as in:

   ```
   \draw [red,  thick, shorten <=-2pt, shorten >=-2pt] (top) to [out=-120, in=90] (left);
   \draw [blue, thick, shorten <=-2pt, shorten >=-2pt] (top) to [out=-60,  in=90] (right);
   ```

### References:

Other tutorial like answers here which might be useful for new `tikz` users include:

- [how to add arrow between arrows, how to put an arrow on a second arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71624/how-to-add-arrow-between-arrows-how-to-put-an-arrow-on-a-second-arrow/71637#71637).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % First, locate each of the nodes and name them
    \node (top) at (0,0) {$\{x,y\}$};
    \node [below left  of=top] (left)  {$x$};
    \node [below right of=top] (right) {$y$};

    % Now draw the lines:
    \draw [red,  thick, shorten <=-2pt, shorten >=-2pt] (top) -- (left);
    \draw [blue, thick, shorten <=-2pt, shorten >=-2pt] (top) -- (right);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate the tutorial way in which you wrote this answer.

Comment: Nice answer. I guess the `at (top)` part in step 2 is souperflous, since it’s overwritten by the `below left` key, isn’t it.

Comment: @Tobi: Good point. But, then these two lines ` \node (top) at (0,0) {$\{x,y\}$};
    \node [below left of=(top)] (left){$x$};` result in `No shape named (top) is known.`.

Comment: It works with `\node [below left of=top] (left) {$x$};` The shape names in this syntax are assumed as names and not as coordinates, unlike as in `at (top)`, so one must omit the parens.

Comment: @Tobi: Ok, have updated the syntax. Please let me know if I missed anything.  Thanks...

Comment: Looks fine to me :-) and if it compiles with the right result it should be ok.

Comment: +1 Just to clarify, you should attach options `in` and `out` to the `to` directive rather than the full path.

Answer (score 45):

Recently, I also had to draw Hasse diagrams, so I post a few examples to get you going. My approach has been rather simple: specifying the nodes and draw the necessary lines between them with --. I just post a few examples to get you going.

Here's a variation of the diamond:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
  \node (one) at (0,2) {$1$};
  \node (a) at (-3,0) {$a$};
  \node (b) at (-1,0) {$b$};
  \node (c) at (1,0) {$c$};
  \node (d) at (3,0) {$d$};
  \node (zero) at (0,-2) {$0$};
  \draw (zero) -- (a) -- (one) -- (b) -- (zero) -- (c) -- (one) -- (d) -- (zero);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This code gives the following Hasse diagram:

[image: Hasse diagram: diamond variation]

Here is an example of a hexagon for the use of polar coordinates:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
  \node (one) at (90:2cm) {$1$};
  \node (b) at (150:2cm) {$b$};
  \node (a) at (210:2cm) {$a$};
  \node (zero) at (270:2cm) {$0$};
  \node (c) at (330:2cm) {$c$};
  \node (d) at (30:2cm) {$d$};
  \draw (zero) -- (a) -- (b) -- (one) -- (d) -- (c) -- (zero);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives as output:

[image: Hasse diagram: hexagon]

And here is a representation of the boolean algebra of subsets of a three element set, to illustrate intersecting lines:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (max) at (0,4) {$(1,1,1)$};
  \node (a) at (-2,2) {$(0,1,1)$};
  \node (b) at (0,2) {$(1,0,1)$};
  \node (c) at (2,2) {$(1,1,0)$};
  \node (d) at (-2,0) {$(0,0,1)$};
  \node (e) at (0,0) {$(0,1,0)$};
  \node (f) at (2,0) {$(1,0,0)$};
  \node (min) at (0,-2) {$(0,0,0)$};
  \draw (min) -- (d) -- (a) -- (max) -- (b) -- (f)
  (e) -- (min) -- (f) -- (c) -- (max)
  (d) -- (b);
  \draw[preaction={draw=white, -,line width=6pt}] (a) -- (e) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which draws the diagram

[image: Hasse diagram: subsets of 3]

Comment: Strange enough, I also find it more easy to work, if I do not use positioning commands, such as above etc. This way you also get better control.

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides: I agree. I wouldn't know how to obtain the result of the first example easily with the positioning commands. The nodes (min) and (max) are below and above the middle of the line from (b) to (c). If you want to get (min) at that position by using below and right or left, you'll probably end up defining a node between (b) and (c) that you otherwise don't want. That seems a bit unnatural. On the other hand, the last diagram would be easy to draw with positioning commands.

Answer (score 3):

With Xy-pic package,

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[all,pdf]{xy}
\usepackage{lmodern,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$$
\def\arl{\ar@{-}}
\xymatrix{
        & \{x,y,z\}\arl[dl]\arl[d]\arl[dr] & \\
\{x,y\}\arl[d]\arl[dr] & \{x,z\}\arl[dl]|\hole\arl[dr]|\hole & \{y,z\}\arl[dl]\arl[d] \\
\{x\}\arl[dr]   & \{y\}\arl[d]   & \{z\}\arl[dl] \\
        & \{\varnothing\} \\
}
$$
\end{document}
```

And you get:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another nice and simple solution:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, row sep=2cm, nodes={minimum width=4cm}]
    {
        $\{x,y\}$ & $\{x,z\}$ & $\{y,z\}$ \\
        $\{x\}$ & $\{y\}$ & $\{z\}$ \\
        & $\{\emptyset\}$ \\
    };
    \path (A-1-1)--(A-1-2) node[above=2cm] (link) {$\{x,y,z\}$};
    
    \foreach \i in {1,...,3}
    \draw (link.south) -- (A-1-\i.north);
    
    \foreach \i/\j in {1/2, 3/2, 2/1, 1/1, 3/3, 2/3}
    \draw (A-1-\i.south)--(A-2-\j.north);
    
    \foreach \i/\j in {1/2, 2/2, 3/2}
    \draw (A-2-\i.south)--(A-3-\j.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile for me. Can you please list the packages you are using, etcetera?