# Using TikZ for a simple drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do you draw a simple figure like the following in TikZ? It seems like the only way to start learning TikZ is by adopting examples, but I found the only two fairly relevant to what I wanted too complicated for what I am trying to achieve here. What I am trying to accomplish by getting a piece of code for this figure, is not only the figure itself, but also insight in *how* TikZ does drawings like these, so I can use it to make similar figures in the future.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the tutorials in the first part of the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz)?

Comment: Concur.  I provide my students with a 15 minute demonstration/introduction to TikZ.  Then they using the first part of the manual, successfully create simple to mildly complicated diagrams.  The very best way to learn TikZ is to do Tikz.  Best wishes.

Comment: Have a look at the example (incl. code) at http://www.texample.net/, especially http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/node-positioning/

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [How to draw a poset Hasse Diagram using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47392/how-to-draw-a-poset-hasse-diagram-using-tikz/47431#47431) which provides a tutorial to get you started.

Comment: All great comments! I'll check out the first part of the manual.

Comment: The resource [A minimal Introduction to Tikz](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) might be less overwhelming than the whole manual. Specifically, page 14-15 has everything I think you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually this is rather simple. There are several ways to do it.
One way would be to place the first node using `\node (NAME) at (POSITION) {TEXT};` and then further nodes using `\node (NAME) [below left=Y and X of NODE] {TEXT};` etc.. Arrows can be drawn using `\draw [->] (NODE1) -- (NODE2);`. Add a trailing `node [OPTIONS] {TEXT}` before the `;` to add labels to the arrows.

```
\documentclass{standalone}% For the example only, any class will do

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% To get more advances positioning options
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% To get more arrow heads

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45,font=\sffamily]
    \node (X) at (0,0) {x};
    \node (Y) [below left=2cm and 1cm of X]  {y};% 2cm below, 1cm to the left (optional)
    \node (Z) [below right=2cm and 1cm of X] {z};
    \node (U) [below left=2cm and 1cm of Z]  {u};
    \draw [semithick,->] (X) -- (Y);
    \draw [semithick,->] (X) -- (Z);
    \draw [semithick,->] (Y) -- (U) node [midway,below,sloped] {*};
    \draw [semithick,->] (Z) -- (U) node [midway,below,sloped] {*};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Looks great! Is it also possible to get the font from mathmode? Could you also tell me what >=triangle 45 stands for?

Comment: @codd To have the font from mathmode, write the node text in mathmode, e.g. `node{$x$}`. `triangle 45` is the name of an arrowhead, which is specified with `>=NameOfArrowhead`.

Answer (score 4):

There are several possibilities to make this graph. The way I prefer is the next code. I avoid 
`\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` because  I prefer to use `scale` than setting `node distance`.
The command `path` is the most important. I use it with relative coordinates `++(-1,-2)`.
`++(-1,-2)` signifies  `below left=2cm and 1cm of X` etc.

Then I use a scope to set some styles. Every paths use `semithick,->` and I prefer with `-- node (U)` by default `pos=.5`. It's preferable to use this syntax because you can use the same with the `to` command.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>    = triangle 45,
                    font = \sffamily,
                    scale= 2]
   \path  (0,  0)  node (X)  {x} 
        ++(-1,-2)  node (Y)  {y}
        ++(1, -2)  node (U)  {u}
        ++(1,  2)  node (Z)  {z};
\begin{scope}[semithick,
              ->,
              every node/.style = {below,sloped}]
   \draw  (X) -- (Y);
   \draw  (X) -- (Z);
   \draw  (Y) -- node  {*} (U) ;
   \draw  (Z) -- node  {*} (U) ;  
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** This method needs explanations. Like the first way, I use `every node` to in the scope to place the labels `*` but  I placed `> = triangle 45` only in the scope because the arrows are used only in this part. Then It's possible to use `edge` instead of `--` but it's interesting to compare how to get the arrows from x and how to get the arrows through u.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font  = \sffamily,
                    scale = 2]
   \path  ( 0,  0)  node (X)  {x} 
        ++(-1, -2)  node (Y)  {y}
        ++( 1, -2)  node (U)  {u}
        ++( 1,  2)  node (Z)  {z};
\begin{scope}[semithick,->,
              > = triangle 45,
              every node/.style = {below,sloped}]
   \draw  (X) edge (Y)
              edge (Z)
          (Y) edge node  {*} (U) 
          (Z) edge node  {*} (U) ;  
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```