# Drawing a diagram with vectors

Tags: xy-pic, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

Is it possible to draw a diagram like this in LaTeX?
[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: What part are you exactly having a problem with? You should make an attempt and ask a specific question when you get stuck.  Perhaps the tutorial at [How to draw a poset Hasse Diagram using TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47392/how-to-draw-a-poset-hasse-diagram-using-tikz) can help get you started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an attempt where `tikz-cd` is used to draw the diagram. This is a 3 by 3 matrix form where

`\arrow{ur}[midway]{label}` means literally draw an arrow one cell up and turn right for one cell. [midway] says put an label/text at midway. Further on drawing arrow,  {ddr} would mean go down for two cells and turn right for one cell.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[margin=20pt,varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass[]{article}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
commutative diagrams/.cd,
arrow style=tikz,
diagrams={line width=1pt}}


\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1cm,column sep=2cm,inner sep=1ex]
           &   \big[10 \big]     & \\
 \overset{+}{0}\overset{+}{0} \arrow{ur}[midway]{\mathbf{x}} \arrow{dr}[midway,swap]{\mathbf{y}}   &             & \bar{1}\bar{1} \arrow{ul}[midway,swap]{ \mathbf{\bar y}} \arrow{dl}[midway]{\mathbf{\bar x}}\\[2ex]
           &     \big[01\big]     &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or with help of `xy` you could do as follows:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,pdf,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{%
&[10]&\\
\overset{+}{0}\overset{+}{0} \ar[ur] ^x \ar[dr] _y && \overset{-}{1}\overset{-}{1}\ar[ul] _{\bar y} \ar[dl] ^{\bar x}\\
&[01]&
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Which yields:

> [image]

I don't know, if the signs over the right side labels mean "minus" or "mean". You may choose whatever you need. I added both.

Comment: but, gives me this error: ! Xy-pic error: No `pdf@@@' option.

Comment: @Maryam Is your system updated? Just leave the `pdf` option away. I am not even sure, if it helps in this case.